# canvas can not make show when i make it dynamically with js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

i made this with html,css,js,jq
[image]

So here is my scene:
I am getting data from api and api tells me how much office, truck (plate license) and user i have

I have to make a line between the user and it's office with canvas
And then with the animation i have to move the plate license between the office and user.

How can i make the line between the user and office? I set the body tag `position:relative;` and canvas and images are `position:absolute;` so i get the coordinate of office and user and i give the coordinate to canvas to make line

---

Here is my code:

css:

```
 #companies {
        }

        .customer {
            margin: 0 0 1px 1px;
            flex: 1;
            width: 50px;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .col-6 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        img {
            width: 100px;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .customer img {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .company img {
            text-align: center;
            justify-content: center;
            display: flex;
        }

        canvas {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 3000;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        body{
            position:relative;
        }
```

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div style="box-shadow: 0 0 9px 2px #eee;height: 100vh;width: 100%;border: none" class="card p-3">
                <p class="text-center pt-3" style="font-family: 'IRANSansWeb(FaNum) UltraLight';font-size: 25px">مشاهده
                    بار های ارسالی</p>
                <div id="companies" style="display: flex;padding: 100px 20px 0 20px">


                </div>

                <div id="trucks">
                    <img id="truck1" src="img/plate.png" width="100" style="position:absolute;"
                         alt="">

                </div>
                <div id="customers" class="mt-3" style=";padding: 200px 20px 0 20px;display: flex">


                </div>
                <div id="canvases">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background: #eee; box-shadow: 0 0 9px 2px #eee;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
 var myMap = new L.Map('map', {
        key: 'web.wB4tHXmSnCW6HSBtvoOefGvDobZ8mDuUId7gNWxk',
        maptype: 'dreamy',
        poi: true,
        traffic: false,
        center: [32.661343, 51.680374],
        zoom: 14,
        zoomControl: false,
    });

    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://sale.bbi.co.ir/API/Navy',
    }).then(function (response) {
        // console.debug(response.data.factory)
        let factory = response.data.factory;

        for (let i = 0; i < factory.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < factory[i].Car_input.length; j++) {
                let latitude_longitude = [];
                latitude_longitude = factory[i].Car_input[j].Coordinates.split(',');
                L.marker([latitude_longitude[0].trim(), latitude_longitude[1].trim()]).addTo(myMap)
            }
        }

        let canvas_number = 0

        for (let i = 0; i < factory.length; i++) {

            let image = document.createElement('img')
            image.src = 'img/office.svg'
            image.width = 100
            image.style.left = '0'
            image.style.top = '0'


            let div = document.createElement('div')
            div.style.margin = '0 0 1px 1px'
            div.style.width = '100px'
            div.style.height = '100px'
            div.style.flex = '1'
            div.classList.add('text-center')
            div.id = 'company' + i
            div.appendChild(image)
            document.getElementById('companies').appendChild(div);

            for (let j = 0; j < factory[i].customers.length;j++) {
                document.getElementById('customers').innerHTML += `<div id="customer${canvas_number}" class="customer"
                         style="margin:0 0 1px 1px;flex: 1; width: 50px;">
                        <img src="img/user.svg" alt="">
                    </div>
                    `

                let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
                canvas.id = 'canvas' + canvas_number
                canvas.width = '1000'
                canvas.height = '1000'
                canvas.style.position = 'absolute'
                canvas.style.zIndex = '999'
                document.getElementById('canvases').appendChild(canvas)
                // document.getElementsByName('body')[0].appendChild(canvas)
                canvas = document.getElementById('canvas' + canvas_number);
                if (canvas.getContext) {
                    let centerXCompany = document.getElementById('company' + i).offsetLeft + document.getElementById('company' + i).offsetWidth / 2;
                    let centerYCompany = document.getElementById('company' + i).offsetTop + document.getElementById('company' + i).offsetHeight / 2;
                    let centerXCustomer = document.getElementById('customer' + i).offsetLeft + document.getElementById('customer' + i).offsetWidth / 2;
                    let centerYCustomer = document.getElementById('customer' + i).offsetTop + document.getElementById('customer' + i).offsetHeight / 2;

                    // console.debug(document.getElementById('canvas4'))
                    console.debug('#company' + i + ' x: ' + centerXCompany + ' y: ' + centerYCompany)
                    console.debug('#customer' + canvas_number + ' x: ' + centerXCustomer + ' y: ' + centerYCustomer)

                    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    console.debug(centerXCompany, centerYCompany, centerXCustomer, centerYCustomer)
                    // Reset the current path
                    context.beginPath();
                    // Staring point (10,45)
                    context.strokeStyle = '#f90089'
                    context.moveTo(centerXCompany, centerYCompany);
                    // End point (180,47)
                    context.lineTo(centerXCustomer, centerYCustomer);
                    // Make the line visible
                    context.stroke();
                }
                canvas_number++;
            }

        }


    });
```

---

**Where is my problem?**
When i make the canvas and images statically it works like a charm. but when i used for and get the data from api i can not show the canvases and canvases are hide (IDK Why)

Here is a picture when i use dynamically:
[image: Now Canvases are hide]

Really appreciate. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not necessary to give ids to dynamically created elements just so you can read them back from the DOM. Within the for loop simply keep a reference to each inserted element. For example `div` is a perfectly good reference to `document.getElementById('company' + i)`.

Comment: `canvas_number` and `i` are synonymous, ... but with the above approach neither will appear used the loop (apart from `i` being the loop counter).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yes my bad. I updated it